# The value of where in Google Calendar is not saved

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, where-clause

In my code, I added an event to Google Calendar. Everything is alright, except that the value in where is not stored.

This is the link to the tutorial I am using to add the event to Google Calendar.

http://mark.biek.org/blog/2010/07/addingdeleting-events-with-the-google-calendar-api/

This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    include('includes/class1.php');
    include('includes/class2.php');
    define("APP_NAME", "MY APP");  
    $email = "test@gmail.com";  
    $password = "test";  
    $altEmail = "test@gmail.com";  
    $login = new GoogleClientLogin($email, $password, GoogleClientLogin::$CALENDAR_SERVICE, APP_NAME);  

    $cal = new GoogleCalendar($login);
    $cal->altEmail = $altEmail;  

     $entryData = $cal->addEvent(array(  
                    "title"=> "Auto Test event",  
                    "content"=> "This is a test event",  
                    "where"=> "Test location",  
                    "startTime"=> time(),
           "endTime"=>  time()
                ));  
    print_r($entryData);    
?>
```

The event is added successfully but location is not saved. What is the problem with my code?

The `class1.php` and `class2.php` are downloaded from the above link.

Answer (score 0):

In class1.php,there have code like:

```
 $xml = '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
                  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event"></category>
                  <title type="text">'.$params["title"].'</title>
                  <content type="text">'.$params["content"].'</content>
                  <gd:transparency value="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.opaque">
                  </gd:transparency>
                  <gd:eventstatus value="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#event.confirmed">
                  </gd:eventstatus>
                  <gd:where valuestring="'.$params["where"].'"></gd:where> 
                  <gd:when endTime="'.$params["endTime"].'" startTime="'.$params["startTime"].'"/>
                </entry>';
```

Here change the  as below:

```
<gd:where valueString="'.$params["where"].'"/>
```

Then it will store the location also